# Enable Istio in fission

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, kubernetes-fission

I have a Kubernetes (v1.10) cluster with **Istio** installed, I'm trying to install **fission**  following  [Enabling Istio on Fission](https://docs.fission.io/0.9.1/tutorial/enabling-istio-on-fission/) guide. when i run

```
[![helm install --namespace $FISSION_NAMESPACE --set enableIstio=true --name istio-demo 
https://github.com/fission/fission/releases/download/0.9.1/fission-all-0.9.1.tgz
```

It throws error saying

```
Error: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

(My cluster has two nodes and one master created using kubespray **all ubuntu 16.04 machines**)

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is probably an authentication failure between helm and the cluster.  Are you able to run `kubectl version`?  How about `helm ls`?

If you have follow up questions, could you ask them on the [fission slack](http://slack.fission.io)?  You'll get quicker answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with helm

**Solution**

Remove .helm folder

```
rm -rf .helm

kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule \
 --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
 --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

helm init --service-account=tiller

kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```